# Match/sort 2 columns in openoffice

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

How do i match/sort my columns A and B to be like the example in the right, in the image below? It is a big list so i cant do it manualy.

What are the steps and formulas? I prefer in openoffice.

[example image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvrqd.png)

Answer (score 0):

[INDEX](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDEX) / [MATCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH) is commonly used as a better alternative to VLOOKUP.  Enter the following formula in E1 and fill down to E3.

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$6;MATCH("*"&A1&"*";B$1:B$6;0))
```

For this to work, wildcards must be enabled in *Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate*.